# Why Maven takes much time in first execution

Tags: maven

Why Maven takes much time during its first execution as compared to the second execution(where it takes much less time).
Is there any sort of dependencies which Maven needs to fetch in first execution.

Comment: ... That's Maven's primary job: resolving dependencies. If the dependency doesn't exist in your local repo it gets downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what happens it downloads all dependencies needed to your machine in the configured local repository usually `[userfolder]/.m2/repository`

Depending on how many dependencies (and its dependencies, called indirect dependencies) your project has it will download all plus the needed dependencies for maven plugins itself. The ones configured in your project and the ones for the normal goals you are executing.

All the downloaded dependencies will be in your local repository for your current project and for the new ones as well.

See here more information about how to set up your local repository [Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#introduction-to-repositories)

Comment: You are very welcome. If it helped you solve your problem please consider in marking it as acceped. You do so by clicking on the V icon on the left. @LAKSHAYARORA